# Keep variable around for async lambda

Tags: c++

I have a asynchronous lambda in a function. How would I keep a capture variable around.

Psuedo Code:

```
void hello()
{
    std::string hi( "This is hello" );

    doSomethingThenCallThisLambda([&]
    {
        std::cout << hi;
    });
}
```

The code above seems to cause memory errors but I am not sure why.

Comment: Capture by copy or use a `shared_ptr` if `static` doesn't work for `std::string hi`.

Comment: @James Campbell do you free the string at any point (i.e. could it be freed before your lambda uses it?)

Comment: *Side remark:* There's an asterisk missing to make `hi` a *pointer to `std::string`*. But I don't see why it should be on the free store `std::string hi("This is hello");`

Comment: @1234567890 Maybe the "memory errors" were caused by the heap alloc?

Comment: I don't free it at any point, I stopped the memory errors by doing a pass by copybut the results with garbage characters. Static works for me, would there be any draw backs to using statics ? should I use the meach time I need this behaviour ? or are shared_pointers the way to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory errors are probably due to the fact that `hi` is destroyed when it goes out of scope. I don't know how `doSomethingThenCallThisLambda` works, but I'm guessing that it doesn't actually call its parameter directly, but rather stores it somewhere, to be called after `hello` returns.

You can use a shared_ptr (note the change to pass-by-value):

```
auto hi = std::make_shared<std::string>("This is hello");

doSomethingThenCallThisLambda([=]
{
    std::cout << *hi;
});
```

Comment: Is there anywhere that explains how these shared_pointers work ? and yes all that function does is it does something asynchronously and once its done the lambda is called which at that point indeed hi is  out of scope.

Comment: If you mean the inner workings, it's anything but simple. If you mean how to use them, there's an abundance of material online; just Google shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr.